# Contenteditable adds a <br> when I hit space

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

I'm not sure why, but if you have an element with contenteditable enabled, the first time you enter a space, it'll append a `<br>` tag into the element.  If the element has a space in it by default (`<p contenteditable="true">this is a test</p>`), it'll be fine, but as soon as the user hits that spacebar (or even copy+pastes a space character), Firefox adds a `<br _moz_dirty="" />` to the `<p>`.

Does anyone have any idea why or a simple fix?  This is my first time playing with contenteditable, so a lot of this is new to me.  At the moment, I'm just using `$('br').remove()` which seems to be working, but I'd love an explanation and a proper way to prevent it if anyone knows.

Comment: Is this still reproducible? I have never encountered such a bug in FF

Comment: I got the same problem, http://jsbin.com/xarirotali/edit?html,css,output
Press two spaces in the end of 'some text' and inspect the p element in FF and it will add a <br>.

Comment: One way to solve this issue by hiding breaks in contenteditables with CSS: `p[contenteditable="true"] br {display:none;}` However this will also prevent carriage return from moving to a new line.

Comment: @jla that solved my problem, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this today and also don't know why Firefox does it. I've dealt with it like this.

```js
function zapTrailingLinebreak (editableNode) {
    let children = Array.from(editableNode.childNodes)

    children.forEach(child => {
        if (children.indexOf(child) == children.length - 1) {
            if (child.tagName && child.tagName === "BR") {
                editableNode.removeChild(child)
            }
        } 
    })
}
```

Comment: useless iteration on children when all you want is the last `<br>`: `[...editableNode.childNodes].pop().tagName == "BR"` will check if the last child is a `<br>`. you need to expand on this logic with a few checks. The problem is to distinguish between a wanted `<br>` and unwanetd one.

Comment: It's not "useless" if it works. The word you meant was "unnecessary". Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Yeah, "unnecessary" sorry, in my language it means identical :) you might have a thousand child nodes and there's no need to iterate them all

Comment: Yes, much better for sure, I remember not being very happy with that code when I wrote it but didn't know a compact way. Spreading childNodes instead of iterating is a smart move that didn't occur to me. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

You can remove extra `BR` tag at end by this

```
let lastTag = document.querySelector('#yourDiv').lastElementChild;
if(lastTag && lastTag.tagName == "BR") lastTag.remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `preventDefault` when the user makes a carriage return. Maybe you could modify it to return a normal space when the user uses the space key.

```
if(e.keyCode==13 && e.shiftKey){ //enter && shift
    e.preventDefault(); //Prevent default browser behavior
    //this.html(this.html+"<br>");
}
if(e.keyCode==13){ //enter
    e.preventDefault(); //Prevent default browser behavior
}
```

Comment: I tried this method but Chrome is giving me this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined`. Do you know why?

Comment: You cannot prevent Firefox to append the <br> with e.preventDefault()

Comment: downvoted because this doesn't answer the question.  The question was specific to firefox adding a `<br _moz_dirty="" />` when pressing **space** not enter/return.

Comment: @MushinNoShin Try reading my answer again. I mention how the example could be modified to fit the use case mentioned in the question.

Comment: @ScottMessinger Fair point, my fault for reading past text too quickly. This suggestion still wouldn't handle when pasting space characters in.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CSS in very simple way

**HTML**

```
<span id="amt" contenteditable="true">100000</span>
```

**CSS**

```
span#amt br {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: This will also display-off (none) any new line on enter by user